# Get next img on each click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a div containing imgs. I've made two arrows(prev, next) inside a large div using as background url the src of one of the imgs from the first div. I'm trying to make the next arrow, when pressed, to change the large image by using the src from the next one. And start from the beginning afterwards(loop).

JQuery:

```
jQuery('#next-arrow').click(function() {
        var yacht_images = jQuery('#yacht-images img');
        var imageUrl = jQuery(yacht_images).nextAll('.yacht-image').attr('src');
        jQuery('#yacht-post-image').fadeTo('slow', 0.1, function(){
            jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow', 1).fadeIn('slow').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
        });
    });
```

PHP:

```
<div id="yacht-post-image" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $post_thumbnail_url; ?>')">
          <div id="prev-arrow"></div>
          <div id="next-arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <?php }
        global $post;
        $images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'yachts_photo', false);
        if ( $images ) {
          echo '<div id="yacht-images">';
          foreach ($images as $image) {
            if ( $image ) {
              $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($image);
              echo '<img class="yacht-image" src="' . $image_url . '"/>';
            }
          }
          echo '</div>';
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it work using this:

```
function change_main_img()
{
    jQuery('#yacht-images img').click(function() {
        var imageUrl = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        jQuery('#yacht-post-image').fadeTo('slow', 0.1, function(){
            jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow', 1).fadeIn('slow').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone more jQuery-adept could do this better:

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/9LeLws40/

```
<style>
#yacht-images img   {
    display: none;
}
#yacht-images,
.newimg {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-size: cover;
}
.newimg {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
</style>
<div id="yacht-post-image">
    <div id="prev-arrow">PREV</div>
    <div id="next-arrow">NEXT</div>
    <div id="curr">1</div>
</div>
<div id="yacht-images">
    <img class="yacht-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg"/>
    <img class="yacht-image" src="http://dc.itamaraty.gov.br/imagens-e-textos/imagens-do-brasil/fauna/alta-fauna15.jpg/image_preview"/>
    <img class="yacht-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Junonia_lemonias_DSF_upper_by_Kadavoor.JPG"/>
    <img class="yacht-image" src="http://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/media/060915/060915_CMB_Timeline300nt.jpg"/> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var yacht_cont      =   $('#yacht-images');
    var yacht_images    =   yacht_cont.children();
    var curr_img        =   0;

    yacht_cont.css({"background-image":"url("+yacht_images[curr_img].src+")"});

    $('#next-arrow').click(function() {
            curr_img    +=  1;
            var ThisImg;
            if(yacht_images[curr_img] == undefined) {
                    curr_img    =   0;
                    ThisImg     =   yacht_images[curr_img].src
                    $(".newimg").remove();
                }
            else
                ThisImg =   yacht_images[curr_img].src;

            $("#curr").html(curr_img+1);
            $('#yacht-images').append("<div class=\"newimg\" style=\" background-image: url("+ThisImg+");\"></div>");
            $(".newimg").fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Rasclatt for your help, I'll give it a try.